# Use of tsconfig.app.json

Tags: angular, typescript

I am unable to understand the use of tsconfig.app.json in src folder in Angular-2 cli project. I know that tsconfig.json is use by typescript compiler, so why tsconfig.app.json?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json files in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898013/difference-between-tsconfig-json-and-tsconfig-app-json-files-in-angular)

Answer (score 14):

There are a few tsconfig.json files in the standard angular project. Here are the one you have asked about:

- The root `tsconfig.json` provides the base options that different config files derive from.
- The app `tsconfig.app.json` provides the options used when working with code in the `app` folder. This allows you to further customize the options from `tsconfig.json`

Other tsconfig files follow the same (base + customization) pattern.

Comment: Can you please elaborate "further customize the options from tsconfig.json" with an example.

Comment: `further customize the options from tsconfig.json` The customizations are mentioned in the file contents

Comment: "Other tsconfig files follow the same (base + customization) pattern." - `tsconfig.spec.json` probably being the most noteworthy.