# Difference between tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json files in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-cli, package.json

I'm a newbie in Angular. I used `angular-cli` to learn about angular and I found the files `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.app.json`. Both of these are typescript related and I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798431/use-of-tsconfig-app-json) useful.

But why two such files has been used? Why can't the configurations in these two files be combined in one file? Please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 48):

there is nothing that prevents you from getting rid of the `tsconfig.app.json`. it's just an additional config file that allows you to adjust your configuration on an app basis. this is e.g. useful when you have multiple apps in the same `angular-cli` workspace.

you could have the root folder with the `tsconfig.json` and then a sub folder `app-a` with a `tsconfig.app.json` file and another app in the sub-folder `app-b` with it's own `tsconfig.app.json`, which contains a variation of the global configuration.

the difference in configuration could e.g. be the output directory `outDir` or the `includes` or `excludes` used.

Comment: I just excluded tsconfig.app.json file at first and then I got this error `no such file or directory, stat '/home/ggg/Documents/SampleAngularApps/sample-ang-app/src/tsconfig.app.json'`. So I had to include this file. I'm using VSCode as the editor. I'm not sure whether this is the thing which is blocking me.

Comment: @kmg You need to modify it in `angular.json` too, that's all

Comment: Does `tsconfig.app.json` override `tsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 26):

The difference is that `tsconfig.app.json` is a file that is related to the Angular App in particular, while `tsconfig.json` is a more general file that contains general typescript configuration. It's especially useful when you have a micro frontends system, where there are multiple Angular subprojects, each of them with its own `tsconfig.app.json` configuration. But if you want you could perfectly merge these two files into one, actually you surely noticed that `tsconfig.app.json` contains the line:

```
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json"
```

which means that the whole App uses the configuration stated in `tsconfig.app.json` plus the configuration in `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 10):

Just want to add one more point.

It seems the `tsconfig.app.json`(App specific one) will override the `tsconfig.json`(global one).

My issue was with the types declaration from node not in scope of my Angular project and I was getting compile errors saying `Buffer` is not found.

I first added the types declaration in `tsconfig.json` thinking it will take effect in every app.
But I had to add it to my app-specific `tsconfig.app.json` file for it to take effect on my app.

Comment: This seems to conflict with fact that tsconfig.app.json **extends** tsconfig.json. Are you sure it wasn't the case that "types" was already defined in both files and it was defined as "[]" in  tsconfig.app.json. This would then be the same as defining "sourceMap" as true in one file and false in the other.

Comment: I have run to the exact same issue. I wanted to add `chrome-types` but if I put it in `tsconfig.json` the project would not compile. I had to add it into `tsconfig.app.json`. It shouldn't be the case as as mentioned `tsconfig.app.json` extends the other.